# Unable to change the global pointsize for lattice displays

Tags: r, lattice

I need to produce a series of PDF plots with the Lattice package in R, with a text pointsize mandated by a journal in which it will be published.

Following the discussion [here,](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Trellis-devices-and-pointize-td4691902.html), I can change the pointsize on a plot by plot basis:

```
library(lattice)
trellis.device("pdf", pointsize=30)
trellis.par.set(fontsize = list(text = NULL))
xyplot(1:10 ~ 1:10)
dev.off()
```

This yields the following plot:

[image]

But then I try to set a global option:

```
library(lattice)
lattice.options(default.theme = list(fontsize = list(text = NULL)))
trellis.device("png", pointsize=30)
xyplot(1:10 ~ 1:10)
dev.off()
```

And this doesn't yield the same results:

[image]

So how can I change the global pointsize for all the Lattice plots?

Comment: How about: `lattice.options(default.theme = list(fontsize = list(text = 30))); trellis.device("pdf"); xyplot(1:10 ~ 1:10); dev.off()`?

Comment: Can you verify the value of `lattice.getOption("default.theme")` after you update it? Did you try running the lines after a fresh R restart? It seems to work for me.

Comment: @jbaums That may work, but I use knits and need the ability to specify different pointsizes for different plots in different chunks. The idea is to set the `dev.args` chunk option to have the correct pointsize, which is then passed to `pdf()`.

Comment: @MrFlick good point. Rechecking my environment I found that I executed the above lines after a call to `lattice.options(default.theme = canonical.theme("pdf", color = FALSE))`. When I then call `lattice.options(default.theme = list(fontsize = list(text = NULL)))`, I see that `lattice.getOption("default.theme")` returns a list whose `fontsize` component has no `text` element, instead of a `text` element that is `NULL`. Is this a bug in the lattice package?

Comment: For me (Win 8.1; R 3.1.0; RStudio 0.98.501), if I run `lattice.options(default.theme = list(fontsize = list(text = NULL))); trellis.device("png", pointsize=30); xyplot(1:10 ~ 1:10); dev.off()` in a new session, the plot resembles your first image, and `lattice.getOption("default.theme")` returns a list with `fontsize$text` set to `NULL`. If I run all of this a second time in the same session, the font size in the generated plot is small (as per your second image), and `lattice.getOption("default.theme")` returns a list with `fontsize` set to `Named list()` as you describe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original question has been answered by jbaums, who suggests using

```
library(lattice)
lattice.options(default.theme = list(fontsize = list(text = 30)))
trellis.device("pdf")
xyplot(1:10 ~ 1:10)
dev.off()
```

which produces precisely what you want:

[image: Imgur]

In the comments, however, you seem to be asking for a way to set defaults using lattice but then pass settings using `dev.args` in knitr. The problem is that `trellis.device(pdf)` calls `default.theme` and my guess is that this overrides the `pointsize = 30` argument you provide. However, if you want to reset this for individual lattice plots it's just a matter of calling `par.settings` for each individual plot, like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

<<setup>>=
library(lattice)
lattice.options(default.theme = list(fontsize = list(text = 8, points = 4)))
@


<<plot, dev='pdf'>>=
xyplot(1:10 ~ 1:10,
       par.settings = list(fontsize = list(text = 25)))
@


<<plot2>>=
xyplot(1:10 ~ 1:10)
@

\end{document}
```